# Serial.println Issue with Flame Sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, error

I'm really new to coding and Arduino so I would be eternally grateful for the help.

I'm trying to make a really basic flame sensor that beeps, lights up an LED and displays the distance from the sensor to the flame when activated. I keep getting a "'Serial' does not name a type" error message for the line that reads - Serial.println(analogRead(A0));

I’ve tried to figure it out from the information on this forum of similar questions to try to correct the issue but it seems like every time I fix one thing another 2 errors come up. I’ve been stuck on this one for a little while so I’m hoping I might be able to receive some kind of assistance from the Arduino community.

Below is the entire code - any help is appreciated, thanks :)

```
int Led = 4;
int Buzz = 7;
int Sensor = 11;
int Fire = HIGH;
void setup()
{ Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(Buzz,OUTPUT);
pinMode(Sensor,INPUT);
pinMode(Led,OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
Fire = digitalRead(Sensor);
if(Fire == HIGH);
Serial.print("analog Read = ");
Serial.print(analogRead);
}
Serial.println("HELP! A FIRE!");
digitalWrite(Buzz,HIGH);
digitalWrite(Led,HIGH);
delay(200);
digitalWrite(Led,LOW);
delay(200);
Serial.println(analogRead(A0));
}
else
{
Serial.println("No fire detected");
digitalWrite(Buzz,LOW);
digitalWrite(Led,LOW);
}
delay(500);
}
```

Comment: You should learn to properly indent your code. You'd soon see the problem then.

Comment: You should also learn the difference between ( and {. And a tutorial like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QO_Jlz1qpDw or equal is recommended.

Answer (score 3):

First things first; please INDENT YOUR CODE. The code you posted is a mess and I took at least double the time to fix that.

First, you have an extra closing curly bracket at line 17 and the `if (Fire == High);` should be changed to `if (Fire == High){`

Fixed code:

```
int Led = 4;
int Buzz = 7;
int Sensor = 11;
int Fire = HIGH;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(Buzz,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Sensor,INPUT);
  pinMode(Led,OUTPUT);
}
void loop()
{
  Fire = digitalRead(Sensor);
  if(Fire == HIGH){
//Serial.print("analog Read = ");
//Serial.print(analogRead);
    Serial.println("HELP! A FIRE!");
    digitalWrite(Buzz,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Led,HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(Led,LOW);
    delay(200);
    Serial.println(analogRead(A0));
 }
 else
 {
    Serial.println("No fire detected");
    digitalWrite(Buzz,LOW);
    digitalWrite(Led,LOW);
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: it looks like the answer helped https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58576149/trying-to-make-a-flame-sensor-code-is-giving-me-the-opposite-to-the-desired-ef

Comment: @Jurag can you flag that as a dupe?

Comment: no, it is a different question and a different site. it is a follow-up question

Comment: Well he took my answer, added a else if, and say that it is his own code. I don't have enough rep over there to comment, can you help me call it out?

Comment: you have the thank you in the question :-). the user60250 account is unregistered, so temporary.